# Is there an alternative to Chosen.js for YUI?

Tags: plugins, yui, selection

I was ask to prettify the UI of out app, namely to replace a default way it renders select elements with something prettier/more customizable.  We are using YUI for the library, and I can't seem to find any plugins for it that would have a functionality similar to Common.js for jQuery.  There's autocomplete, but it requires typing, and we need to retain the behavior of the select element, while replacing its look.
Is anyone aware of any YUI plugins to do that or would I have to build one from scratch?

Thanks!
Luka

Answer (score 1):

Nothing as nifty as Chosen.js. There are a couple of enhancers for select elements in the Gallery: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/itsaselectlist, which makes select elements more button-like, and http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/multiselect, which turns a multiple select box into a slightly fancier list of checkboxes.

If you do create a Chosen.js clone in YUI, consider submitting it to the Gallery, it would be a great addition!